# Unusual rise in pageviews with no increase in unique visitors

Tags: high-traffic, page-views

There has been an unusual raise in my website page views.  During the day I usually get 40-50 page views per minute, but its a few days now that i'm getting about 150 page views/ minute, and there is no significant change in visitor count.

The first time that I saw that, I thought it might be a bot, like Googlebot. I don't think Google but likes me so much that it won't leave my site.

What can cause this? Can it indicate a problem?

My website is a free website offering baby names with their meaning. There is nothing special to hack.

EDIT:
the new thing in a few days is that I have got a company place ads in mywebsite and each ad loads in an iframe. can it be cause it? does google analytics count iframes too?
the content of iframes are some ads from that company and absolutely has no analytics script.

Comment: Are you able to see from your stats who/what is causing all the page views? Is it a single entity? Have you completely ruled out Googlebot? For instance, it could be possible that Googlebot has recently found a URL with a variable querystring and it is simply going through all the possibilities (in which case it probably needs to be blocked).

Comment: can i see who is doing it from google analytics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen a coding problem that can cause extra page "views".  We had an empty image tag on a page that looked like this:

```
<img src="">
```

Because we had a base href on the pages, that caused Internet Explorer to fetch the home page instead and try to load it as an image.    Other browsers seemed to ignore the tag.

---

It would help to know how you are measuring.   Is it log files or is it analytics triggered by javascript?   Are the extra hits to a specific set of files?    Is it a specific visitor that is fetching lots of pages, or are most visitors fetching more pages than they used to?